# What matrix corresponds to differentiation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, derivatives, linear-transformations

Today, in my linear algebra class, we discussed how differentiation of polynomials of degree at most $4$ can be defined using the following matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4\end{bmatrix}$$

since differentiation is a linear transformation. My question is the following

> Is there a way to represent differentiation using a matrix when we consider the space of *all differentiable functions* with domain and codomain $\mathbb{R}$?

Note: I've studied set theory, so if the matrix has uncountably many entries, that's fine. Axiom of choice is fine as well.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no, and the long answer includes the fact that the space of all differentiable functions on $\Bbb{R}$ is infinite dimensional. The matrix representation you give above relies on the fact that fourth degree polynomials have a basis with 5 elements: $1, x, x^2, x^3$, and $x^4$.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a (Hamel) *basis* for the space of differentiable functions, then like any linear transformation, differentiation is represented in coordinate form by a matrix.

It will be big (its dimensions would be uncountably infinite!), and unlikely to have a nice form unless you *carefully* construct a basis. (and there is surely not any *nice* construction for such a basis)

Answer (score 1):

Speaking on a intuitive basis:

The indices of a matrix $\in \mathbb N$, so are countably infinite, and and infinite matrix can operate on  countably infinite vectors, which means functions which are expressible by a series (eg. Fourier).

To  "extend the matrix to real indices" you shall pass to a function of two variables $K(x,y)$ so that $g(x) = \int {K(x,y)f(y)dy} $ , like for instance in [Volterra's integral equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra_integral_equation).

Answer (score 0):

We can, for example, define the differentiation operator $D$ as a linear transformation from $C^1(\mathbb{R})$, the space of all differentiable functions on $\mathbb{R}$ with continuous derivatives, to $C^0(\mathbb{R})$, the space of all continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$. However, the immediate obstacle is that is that both of these spaces are *infinite dimensional* and thus don't have a finite basis. This means there can be no representation of $D$ as a matrix.

We can however obtain such a matrix if we restrict $D$ to a finite dimensional subspace of $C^1(\mathbb{R})$. Then the range of this restriction is also necessarily finite dimensional as well. We can then obtain a matrix representation in a manner entirely analogous to the construction you saw with 4th degree polynomials. In fact, you can view the example you saw in class as a specific case of doing exactly that.

Comment: Matrices can't have infinite rows and columns?

Comment: @PyRulez You can define such a thing, but this would require that the dimension of both spaces be countable, which neither of these are.

Comment: why, do the number of rows and columns need to countable?

Comment: @PyRulez What would such a matrix look like in the case of uncountable dimension?

Comment: There are tricks you could use to get around this to some extent, by well-ordering uncountable bases for each space for example, but it's not anything remotely constructable and not terribly illuminating.

Comment: @PyRulez If you really want to think seriously about infinite dimensional vector spaces, the right subject to look at is called _functional analysis_. Most treatments require you to know quite a bit more than you probably do now, but Kreyszig's book on the topic is fairly accessible.

Comment: @ChristianSykes: Given any two index sets $I$ and $J$, it makes sense to talk about $I \times J$ matrices. It's just convention that we usually pick $I$ and $J$ to be initial segments of the natural numbers, or of the natural numbers with $0$ excluded.